# Can I use an excel formula to extract the link location of a hyperlink in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have a spreadsheet with a large number of cells containing hyperlinks with display text different than the hyperlink location

ie:

*cell location: A1*

*display text = "Site Info"*

*hyperlink location = "http://www.mylocation.com"*

Is there an excel formula that allows me to access the text string of the hyperlink location?

Ideally it would look like this:

**FORMULA(A1) = "http://www.mylocation.com"**

Comment: Actual hyperlinks (Insert>>Hyperlink) or hyperlinks using `=HYPERLINK()` ?

Comment: Does it have to be a formula? There are lots of VBA solutions.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I only needed to extract the address from a single cell's value so I found this small function handy:

> Instead of a "brute force" macro, you could also create a user-defined
>   function that would extract and return the URL for any hyperlink at
>   which it was pointed:

```
Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
     On Error Resume Next
     GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address 
End Function
```

> In this case you can place it where you want. If you want, for
>   example, the URL from a hyperlink in A1 to be listed in cell C25, then
>   in cell C25 you would enter the following formula:
>
> =GetURL(A1)

http://excel.tips.net/T003281_Extracting_URLs_from_Hyperlinks.html

Comment: Works like a charm! Place this snippet in a new "module" in the VBA of your Excel file (not just the sheet).

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution, Matthew! 

For me, the result truncates when it encounters a hashtag (#). Any idea how to modify the code to account for that?

Comment: @SAL see gilly3's comment in the answer below. I also added an answer with code.

Answer (score 75):

You can use a macro:

- Open up a new workbook.
- Get into VBA (Press Alt+F11)
- Insert a new module (Insert > Module)
- Copy and Paste the Excel user defined function below
- Get out of VBA (Press Alt+Q)
- Use this syntax for this custom Excel function: =GetURL(cell,[default_value])

  ```
   Function GetURL(cell As range, Optional default_value As Variant)
   'Lists the Hyperlink Address for a Given Cell
   'If cell does not contain a hyperlink, return default_value
        If (cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count <> 1) Then
            GetURL = default_value
        Else
            GetURL = cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address
        End If
  End Function
  ```

Comment: @igor Why are you using "range("a1") in cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count and cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address ? I've copied your macro but took it out (-->cell.hyperlinks.count and cell.hyperlinks(1).adress)  and it works perfectly. I'm curious on  the purpose of the  "range("a1") here.

Comment: This suppose to treat if there are multiple links inside the hyperlink. it was just an idea, great it worked with your adjustments. :)

Comment: If your hyperlink includes a document fragment (eg, `#something`), that is stored in the `SubAddress`, so you will need to concatenate `Address`, `"#"`, and `SubAddress`.

Comment: Since parameter `cell` is a range object it can contain more than one cell. 
 `Range("A1")` could be rewritten as `Cells(1)`.  It instructs the function to only consider the first cell in parameter `cell`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked better than in Google Sheets (which is rare case lol:) Important things to not forget: save Excel file as a Macro enabled workbook; Insert formula in new module (not in sheet or workbook code); name of function is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

```
function EXTRACT_URL(input) {

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input);
  var re = /^.+?\(\"(.+?)\",.+?$/;
  if (input.indexOf(':') != -1) {
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    for (var i in formulas) {
      for (var j in formulas[i]) {
        formulas[i][j] = formulas[i][j].replace(re, "$1");
      }
    }
    return formulas;
  } else {
    return range.getFormula().replace(re, "$1");
  }

}
```

Comment: In other that leave off the quote marks pass in the cell reference by using this in the spreadsheet =EXTRACT_URL(ADDRESS(row(A4),1,4)) . Otherwise you have to hardcode the range reference.  Then you can copy this function from one cell to another.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open up a new workbook.
2. Get into VBA with Alt+F11 (Fn + Opt + F11 for MAC)
3. Insert a new
   module (Insert > Module)
4. Copy and Paste the Excel user defined
   function below
5. Press F5 and click “Run” Get out of VBA (Press Alt+Q)

> ```
> Sub ExtractHL()
> Dim HL As Hyperlink
> For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
> HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address
> Next
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as @SAL

I found that the `.Hyperlink` object actually splits the address into `.Address` and `.SubAddress` if it encounters a delimiter. "#" is one such delimiter (I don't know if there are others).

See @gilly3 's comment above and this other StackOverflow question:
[hyperlinks(1).address only returning a partial address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239925/hyperlinks1-address-only-returning-a-partial-address)

Also Microsoft's (incomplete) documentation on .SubAddress:
[Hyperlink.SubAddress property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.subaddress)

One thing not mentioned anywhere is that the "#" delimiter is not included in either `.Address` or `.SubAddress` so if you want an address that will actually work as a full URL, you have to add the "#" delimiter back in.

With that, I modified @Matthew Lock's code as follows, also including the possibility of multiple hyperlinks being stored from @Igor O and my addition of "#":

```
 Function getURL(rng As Range) As String
     On Error Resume Next
     fullURL = ""
     For Each HL In rng.Hyperlinks
    
         If Len(HL.SubAddress) > 0 Then
             fullURL = fullURL & HL.Address & "#" & HL.SubAddress & " "
         Else
             fullURL = fullURL & HL.Address & " "
         End If

     Next

     getURL = fullURL

 End Function
```

This should return a text string of all hyperlinks in full (I added a space at the end so if there's more than one, they are separated).

Comment: Not sure how a range can have multiple hyperlinks, unless more than one cell is selected, in which case, does concatenating them all actually work? Otherwise, thank you for accounting for the hashtag!

Comment: @SAL not normally. at least if the range is just a cell, at least not through the normal UI. However, if the range is more than just a cell, there could be links in each cell. So I accounted for it in the code. If there is only one hyperlink, without or without a SubAddress, this will work directly as a link. If you have multiple hyperlinks, you'd have to parse them with another function or command.  You couldn't directly use them in a link that way, but at least all the data would be in the string produced.