# How to convert a list of HTML links to a list of URL only?

Tags: conversion, url, microsoft-onenote, hyperlink

I have a list of HTML links (stored in OneNote 2016), and I want to convert them to text form, with both title and url. So for example, I want to convert

> [Super User](https://superuser.com)

to

> Super User: https://superuser.com

Or

> - [Super User](https://superuser.com)

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I'm confused. Your first example `[Super User](https://superuser.com) 
` is already in the right format?

Comment: well, yes and no. Yes because it is stored in the HTML-supported editor, so it can be displayed like that. But when I want to copy it to a plain-text-only editor, I need to convert it to other forms. This can be easily done by hand for one or two links, but when it is a list, it's burdensome

Comment: If you use notepad++ then they would be trivial regep search and replaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Excel as a tool to get the list.

1. Copy your original list from OneNote into the clipboard.
2. Paste it into new Excel sheet, column **A**.
3. Use an [URL-extracting function](https://superuser.com/questions/593492/can-i-use-an-excel-formula-to-extract-the-link-location-of-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell) to extract the URLs of links in column **A** into column **B**.
4. Paste your sheet with columns **A** and **B** into your target text file. Done.